# Displaying posts on a page that have been assigned a value in a database

Tags: filters, database, query

I have a wordpress site with a bunch of posts that I need to display on a page, depending on their value in a database.

To be more specific, out of 20 posts I would only want to display the posts on the page that have been "liked" in a third-party program. This third-party program will, once a piece of content have been liked, assign a value to a post in the database. Whenever a user then loads my page, I only want the posts with this value assigned to show.

My guess is to use post categories and taxonomy, but I would like to pick your brains on how to execute it properly.

What I need to resolve:

- Do I need a 2nd database to control this? Or am I able to externally from Wordpress assign a value to a post.
- Is taxonomy the best way to go about this?
- How can I implement a solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to accomplish, you'll probably want "post meta" (post meta data) to be updated in relation to the 3rd party program, then adjust the post query to look for it before outputting posts.

This objective can be accomplished in different ways, the simplest ones not necessarily requiring input from or interaction with the 3rd party program: For instance, when a particular button is clicked, the post meta could be added, with all operations taking place within your installation.

It's also very possible, however, that the implementation is already adding post meta data, in which case all you'll need do is identify it. You might try outputting the results of get_post_meta() for a particular likely post, and seeing if there are any keys that look like what you want.

Either way, you would then use a query argument looking for the post meta value (aka custom field value) to determine which posts are output using WP Query. You can find details and some simple examples in the WordPress Codex here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This definitely brought me one step closer!

I think I have a pretty good idea now of how to manage the posts on the wordpress end, but I still need some info on how to manage the posts from outside of my wordpress installation. Can I write directly to post meta from a 3rd party program?

Comment: In a word, no, but in a way, sure. To keep the explanation simple, you'll effectively always be enabling or authorizing a third party to write to your site in any way, but a lot of these authorizations occur invisibly: For example, last I checked (this stuff is subject to change), when you embed a tweet in a post, the content of the tweet and other data are all entered as post meta, but the process has been pre-authorized. So, in one sense Twitter is writing "directly" to post meta, and you can find the data and use it, but it's only happening because passive authorization is built in.